# Saving the output of a process run by python

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```py
import os

commands = [r"cd c:\bugs\*722857\*722857 && chrome.exe --no-sandbox --single-process ..\..\cr-1195650-cve-2021-30588-stepped.html",
            r"cd c:\bugs\*722857\*722857 && chrome.exe --no-sandbox --single-process --js-flags=-expose-gc ..\..\cr-1057593-cve-2020-6428-stepped.html",
            r"cd c:\bugs\*722857\*722857 && chrome.exe --no-sandbox --single-process ..\..\cr-1032000-stepped.html",            
            ]

for i in commands:
    os.system(i)
```

I would like to save the output of each command, either as a string or list of strings. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a look at `subprocess` module. Either `subprocess.getstatusoutput` or `subprocess.getoutput` is matching your requirement. If you just want to save the output, the return value from `subprocess.getoutput` is enough.

Comment: When running with subprocesses, either with check_output or popen, I get a file not found error, so I was hoping to use os if possible

Comment: If you are creating Popen object by subprocess.Popen, please note, the argument `shell` need to set True, as your input are some commands. like proc = subprocess.Popen('cd c:\somelocation\ && ...', shell=True, ...)

Comment: when using something like: for i in commands: out = subprocess.Popen(i, shell=True) it only runs one command

Comment: Based on your code, does chrome.exe is your %PATH% envirement? if not, I think it will raise 'FileNotFound'.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `os.system(i)` with `output = os.popen(i).read()`, as the first one only passes command to the system, while the second creates a pipe to communicate with whatever is executed.

Comment: I'm trying to use .upper() on the output, but it doesn't seem to be working, any recommendations?

Comment: How are you doing it?

Comment: output = os.popen(i).read() then output = output.upper(), then print (output)

Comment: @NetMax And how exactly is it not working? It works for me on python 3.10 and should work.